# Unable to start a bounty even after grace period!

Tags: support, bounty

I have posted a question 6 days ago and my current total points are 54 but I am still unabel to start a bounty for the question. What should I do ? Question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131822/parsed-soap-response-is-different-with-the-received-response)

Comment: It says "edited 2 days ago". This could be the reason. I am not sure though

Comment: @LazyNinja I see, in that case please vote up the question to attract more viewers thanks.

Comment: @JackMoore, it seems that it is your rep is not enough yet. Thanks I learned a new thing too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have 75 reputation points before you can start a bounty.

Source https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Since you're at 54 rep now, you are very close. There are many ways to possibly earn rep, including answering questions, editing posts, and asking good questions.